# Java: Using multiple DataInputStreams on single FileInputStream

Tags: java, datainputstream

Suppose I have the following code in Java:

```
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filename);
        DataInputStream x = new DataInputStream(fin);
        DataInputStream y = new DataInputStream(fin);
        DataInputStream z = new DataInputStream(fin);
```

I want to use `y.skip(100)` and `z.skip(200)` to simultaneously read data from the file at different positions. Will this work? I'm getting EOF errors at the moment...

EDIT

I did try the following code:

```
        FileInputStream fin1 = new FileInputStream(filename);
        FileInputStream fin2 = new FileInputStream(filename);
        FileInputStream fin3 = new FileInputStream(filename);
        DataInputStream x = new DataInputStream(fin1);
        DataInputStream y = new DataInputStream(fin2);
        DataInputStream z = new DataInputStream(fin3);
```

This does not produce EOF errors, but still not sure if this might return corrupted data?...

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution. The original doesn't work because it just increments the file pointer every time, regardless of the `DataInputStream` used. Instead I needed to create additional `FileInputStreams`'s. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case it won't produce corrupted data, but if there had been a `BufferedInputStream` anywhere in association with them it would have.

The real question is why on earth you would want to do this? Why can't you use the same `DataInputStream?`

Comment: I have a legacy data file containing 3d vector field data. All x values are stored first then all the y values and then all the z values, ie the data doesn't  read as (x,y,z) each time. I could loop trhough the data 3 separate times, but this is onefficient on large data sets. Maybe theres another way to achieve what i want? I have no control over the data file.